# Cannot target url attribute in Objective C XML parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing

I'm putting together an iOS RSS reader that displays the feed by title in a UITableView, then plays the audio corresponding to each XML item when you click on the appropriate UITableViewCell.

I've tried a variety of ways, **the best thing I've been able to do is load and play the mp3 from the first item in the feed, but no matter which item in the UITableView I click on it always plays the same audio file.**. I've switched things around since then to try and make it work and now I get an uncaught exception at "[item setObject:file forKey:@"file"];" in AFAPodcastsController.m.

Using this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-rss-reader-tutorial/) I haven't had much issue being able to go from the appropriate title to link (if I wanted to just display the item's link in a UIWebView), but targeting the associated mp3 file has been much more tricky.

The xml file is here [Duncan Trussell RSS feed](http://lavenderhour.libsyn.com/rss), and the mp3 file is in an attribute called "url" of the  tag.

Here is where I am currently at in my attempts to make this work...

The .h file for the VC that parses the XML and loads the tableview:

```
@interface AFAPodcastsViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;



@end
```

The .m

```
#import "AFAPodcastsViewController.h"
#import "AFADetailViewController.h"

@interface AFAPodcastsViewController ()  {

NSXMLParser *parser;
NSMutableArray *feeds;
NSMutableDictionary *item;
NSMutableDictionary *attributes;
NSMutableArray *attributesArray;
NSIndexPath *newIndex;
NSMutableString *title;
NSMutableString *link;
NSMutableString *file;
NSString *element;

}




@end

@implementation AFAPodcastsViewController



- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{

    UINavigationItem *navItem = self.navigationItem;
    //Set the title of the item
    navItem.title = @"Podcasts";


}

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://lavenderhour.libsyn.com/rss"];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

[parser setDelegate:self];
//[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
return cell;
}



- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath
{
AFADetailViewController *detailView = [[AFADetailViewController alloc]  
initWithNibName:@"AFADetailViewController" bundle:nil];
 indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
//Store indexPath in a variable incase I want to use it elsewhere
newIndex = indexPath;
NSString *string =[feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"file"];
[detailView setUrl:string];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
namespaceURI: (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes: 
(NSDictionary 
*)attributeDict {

element = elementName;

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
{
    //The "file" variable is for storing the mp3.
    //I tried using an array to store the attributes info incase I wanted to target a  
value by index.
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    title = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    file = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [attributes addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];
   // attributesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}
/*The below code would be for targeting the enclosure tag as soon as the parser finds the 
element. */
/* else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"])
{
    file = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [attributes addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];
   attributesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
} */


}




- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:
 (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    //[attributesArray addObject:[attributes objectForKey:@"url"]];
     [item setObject:file forKey:@"file"]; //<--This is where the exception happens
     [feeds addObject:[item copy]];
}

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"] ) {
    [title appendString:string];

} else if ([element isEqualToString:@"enclosure"])
{

    file = [attributes objectForKey:@"url"];

}


}







- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

[self.tableView reloadData];

} 





@end
```

The .h file for the VC that plays the audio

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AFADetailViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *url;

- (IBAction)play:(UIButton *)sender;



@end
```

The .m

```
#import "AFADetailViewController.h"
#import "AFAPodcastsViewController.h"


@interface AFADetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation AFADetailViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

_webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
  NSLog(@"%@", self.url );

}


- (void) loadAudio {


NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.url    
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *urlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:urlData error:NULL];
self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [self.audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
[self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.audioPlayer play];

}



- (IBAction)play:(UIButton *)sender {
[self loadAudio];


}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I shouldn't have been using indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; and I accidentally used tableView:DidDeselectRowAtIndexPath instead of tableView:DidSelectRowAtIndexPath